# Svelte: is there a way to modify property in layout file from a slot component or from a parent layout?

Tags: javascript, svelte, sveltekit

In `routes/home/__layout.svelte`, there is a variable:

> let activeId;

Is it possible to modify the `activeId` from:

1. `routes/home/content.svelte`, which will use the above layout.
2. `routes/__layout.svelte`, which is a parent layout of the above layout.

Comment: My another thought would be replace part of the layout with a component, which I would have more control over.

Answer (score 2):

I would probably just use a store that is made available through a [context](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-setcontext) that is set in the root layout.